# How do I prove multiplication of two summation?

Tags: measure-theory, summation, proof-explanation, solution-verification

How do I prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {a_i . b_i} \ne \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i} . \sum_{i=1}^{n} {b_i}$ with general cases?

I only know using variables:

Let k be the variable and it can be translated as sum of ${k_i}$, from i = 1 to n:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{k_i} = {k_i} + {k_i+1} + {k_i+2}$ ... = ${k_{n-1}} + {k_n}$

Is it a good direction?

Answer (score 3):

It helps to write the right-hand side as $\sum_ia_i\sum_jb_j=\sum_{ij}a_ib_j$, while the left-hand side is $\sum_ia_ib_i=\sum_{ij}a_ib_j\delta_{ij}$ in terms of the Kronecker delta.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to realize that when you expand $\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)$, you get $n^2$ terms $a_ib_j$, one for each ordered pair $\langle i,j\rangle$ of indices in the range $1,\ldots,n$:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)=\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}a_ib_j\,,$$

the sum of all possible products of the form $a_ib_j$. The sum $\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i$ has only $n$ terms and includes only the products in which $i=j$.

One way to visualize this is in terms of the $n\times n$ matrix $A=[a_ib_j]$: $\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i$ is the sum of the entries on the main diagonal of $A$, and $\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)$ is the sum of all of the entries in $A$. Clearly these are not in general equal when $n>1$.